# Layout-neutral tag for CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is there an "invisible" tag in HTML (4) that I can use to make CSS distinctions

```
tag.myclass tag.mysubclass h1 {  }
```

without having **any** visual impact on the HTML rendered?

My background is that I have areas in a form that belong to different groups. As I am opening those in lightboxes (long story involving DOM operations and such, not really important) I don't want to rely on the usual `div class=x` or `span class=y` to style the subsequent elements, as I would have to reset margins here, paddings there, and so on.

A layout-neutral wrapping tag would be just what I need in such situations.

Comment: If you've given the class-less and id-less DIV element padding and margins, then you've made a mistake. The purpose of this tag is precisely what you're asking for here. So, if you've broken the purpose of the tag ... I suggest you fix that and use it.

Comment: Mmm, you're right about the margins and paddings, but DIV is a block element and thus not layout-neutral even if reset completely. It will always try to stretch to 100% width by default and so on.

Comment: I think it's best to think of the addition of a wrapper DIV as a benefit that can be used to your advantage.  You can position elements in a simple way, by grouping them.  DIVide and conquer ;) (sorry, couldn't help myself)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not.

(And that's because such an element wouldn't really fit into the rest of HTML. The only reason DIV and SPAN affect the surrounding area is because they're block and inline elements, respectively. What would an 'invisible' element be? If you need something that's completely independent, absolutely (or relatively) position it and give it a higher z-index.)

Comment: \*cough\* `<font>` tag \*cough\* ;)

Comment: Don't resurrect the dead! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to group elements use a div or a span tag as a wrapper element.  Apply your id or class to this, and style it accordingly.

**EDIT**

There isn't an 'invisible' tag - but margins and padding can be easily reset 'margin: 0; padding: 0;'

Answer (score 5):

While all browsers give default styling to many HTML tags, at it's core HTML only *describes* data, it doesn't format it.

What you're probably looking for is a DIV tag, because no browser gives any default styling to that tag.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a [<fieldset>](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_fieldset.asp).

Comment: That usually comes with some borders in the UI from memory... I could be mistaken though...

Comment: Yes, I think a fieldset is not "invisible". Still, it would be a good tag to reset and "misuse" for the purpose in question. +1.

Comment: fieldset behaves as div at best, but it can behave much worse

Comment: True, a <fieldset> comes with default browser styles, which can be difficult to reset.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say a **span** tag is as neutral as they come. I don't think there's any browser that applies a margin nor a padding and it just wraps around it's contents.

Comment: This is not generally advisable if you want to put divs or other block elements inside.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432397/how-to-display-a-div-element-inside-a-span though it seems to work in my browser http://codepen.io/nueverest/pen/grVKVJ

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can use <object> tag without usual attributes for that purpose, but I haven't tested it thoroughly yet. It's even in HTML5 (unlike FONT tag).

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is use a div tag and define a class for it. Here is an example:

```
<h2 style="font-size: 14px">Project 1 - Project 2 
  <div class="username">{% if request.user.is_authenticated%} Welcome {{request.user.username}} {% endif %}</div>
</h2>
```

then in your css file you can have a class like this:

```
.username {
    color:white; 
    float:right;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

voila!! It all belongs to h2 tag but the user name has a different css applied.

Answer (score -1):

You can add `display: none;` to it. That won't display it (obviously).

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. I mean a surrounding tag (a wrapper) that in itself has no visibility, but in which all child elements are rendered as if the wrapper were not there.