# What HTML tag should be used for semantically meaningless design?

Tags: html

I understand that content should be separated from presentation, but sometimes adding HTML elements for the sake of design is unavoidable. Usually I would use a div, but is this the best way?

What is the best HTML element to hold semantically meaningless design (no text, images, logos etc...) ?

Comment: I asked the same (or a very similar) question once: [Layout-neutral tag for CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751765/layout-neutral-tag-for-css)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by semantically meaningless design? Can you describe in greater detail what you are trying to accomplish?  How about an example of what you mean by meaningless design?

Comment: `<span>` is usually the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest `<div>`'s for block level elements and `<span>`'s for inline elements. If you are placing these inside an element that only allows its children to be inline (but you would like the element to be block) use a `<span>` and use CSS to display it as block. *Cringe!*
I know this seems obvious (since you pretty much answered your own question), but the purpose of `<div>`'s and `<span>`'s are to make up for the lack of a semantically proper element.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `<div>` (block) or `<span>` (inline).