# How to display a <div> element inside a <span>?

Tags: html

My container element is a `<span>` and I want to display a `<div>` element inside it. How can I add a `<div>` inside a `<span>` without making the `<div>` `display: inline;`?

```
<span>
    <div>Content goes here</div>
</span>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of it? A <div> inside a <span> is considered bad practice and I'd advise you to change your CSS if appropriate.

There may be a good reasoning for it though, but this question doesn't give enough details for an answer.

Comment: Why would you want to insert a _block_ element in an _inline_ element?

Comment: cos i have made use of span as container and now i am using jQuerys Data Tables to generate dynamic data grid, which has search panels and some elements made of DIV's and it not working.. i have changed the display rule to inline for DIVs but not looking good..

Comment: HTML elements are not arbitrarily interchangeable.  What you want to do is like wearing your underpants outside your trousers- sure you can, but it's not very functional and people will think you look funny.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change the span to display block?
But it makes no sense at all, if you need a block inside, then replace the span with a div.
Your document won't validate this way either and behavior in different browsers is kinda unpredictable...

Comment: Not really that helpful, nor really that accurate. Borderline smug, cocky or rude, and definitely useless. The intention makes sense. Obviously he wants to know how to get multiple divs in a line. The mechanism is what he's asking for help with and your answer doesn't address the intention at all, so it's kind of a waste of time. There is a very good an easy answer, which you didn't provide, that another more thoughtful and considerate answer did, below.

Comment: At the time you wrote that, 2011, inline-block might not have been available, but float was, so you could have at least attempted to answer the real question.

Comment: If you read my answer you would see that it states:
Change the span to display block

Comment: @nerdistcolony I disagree. The *best* answer on SO is to provide guidance and correction when a question shows that the OP is misunderstanding the spec. One of the most basic, core tenets of HTML design is that inline elements do not contain block elements, and that you select elements for their use based on semantics. So, while Han did not answer the question by providing a way to make the OP's markup structure work, he did the right thing by telling the OP how to do it *correctly* which is by far more important.

Comment: In all fairness, @HanDijk told him to change it to `display: block` and that is certainly a way to accomplish that task. He merely gave him further insight beyond the answer he was seeking.

Comment: @clearlight `inline-block` most certainly was available in 2011 :)

Answer (score 18):

What I ended up doing when I first **thought** I needed this was changed the span to a div.  But instead of leaving the div as a display:block (default)  I specified the style to be display:inline-block, this allowed the block so the inner div could be used, but still allowed me to put more then one of the divs on the same line.

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <div>context on top</div>
  <div>context on bottom</div>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <div>context on top</div>
  <div>context on bottom</div>
</div>
```

This should put 2 blocks next to each other (with out the use of float) and inside of each block there should be 2 blocks one on top of each other.  Also you can specify the width on the style to get it to look the way you want.

Comment: Yes. Good answer - clarifying how one can get multiple blocks in the same line without the ugly outdated float.

Comment: Clean. Simple. Works like a charm. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

According to given vague description:

```css
.A {
  position: relative;
}
.B {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="A">text<div class="B">div</div></span>
```