# Display a Div Element Inside a Span Block

Tags: html, css

I have a span block, how do I display a DIV element inside the span block.

I have tried changing the div block to span but the UI elements doesn't fit well. How do I fix this.

**I am facing many issues with IE7** using answers mentioned in the above link. That's the reason why I raised a different question over here.

Comment: Divs should not be put in spans.

Comment: @123 : `span` is `inline` level element mate...`div` is block level....better use `div` with `display:inline` if thats what you want to do!! :)

Comment: Why do it this way? Schematically there are better ways of laying out your page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To Display DIV element inside SPAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432397/to-display-div-element-inside-span)

Comment: @Paulie_D Why should DIV not be put in a SPan. Please explain, I am facing many cross browser issues because of this.

Comment: @NoobEditor Thanks Noob Hopefully that can help.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've tried all the solutions mentioned in them. I am facing issues in IE7 by using inline-block.

Comment: @123 - inline-block won't work in IE7 I'm afraid

Comment: @123 - I suspect it's your HTML that is wrong somewhere. There should be no reason to place a block level element in a `<span>`. Perhaps you could show us the HTML.

Comment: I am facing many issues with IE7 using answers mentioned in the above link. That's the reason why I raised a different question over here.

Comment: @123 - please provide a JSFiddle or post your code

Comment: IE7 should not be used anymore, even Microsoft says so! If it is client work, tell them to torture someone else. Writing IE7 conform html code is like riding a bicycle backwards with no handle bar, and blindfolded down a steep hill. Afterall it is 2014!

Comment: @mahatmanich - unfortunately many people I know (mainly clients) still use IE7, and also IE9 in Compatibility mode. Personally though, I only build for IE8 upwards and charge extra for IE7 support :)

Comment: Well then there is big bucks in that market share :-P, maybe you should look at some of the shims e.g. modernizr or html5shiv to make your live easier, before you start wrapping divs in spans :-)

Comment: Further it would really help if you posted some of your UI html that does not fit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A div should never be placed in side a span. A div is a block element and a span is an inline element (more info [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)). If you REALLY insist though, you need to set the CSS of your span to be `span {display:block;}`.

Would still advise against this though, as it is not semantically correct and will fail validation.

**From comment:** Basically block elements are used for layout, whereas inline elements are used to style bits of text. For example, if you wanted a certain word to be a different style, you'd wrap a span around it. Through CSS you can set the display property of either element to be whatever you want, but this should only be a last resort, as you will most likely end up failing validation and causing more issues.

Comment: What's the difference between using display:block for a span and inline:block for a div. I am afraid, I faced may cross browser issues.

Comment: @123 - Please read the "more info" link I provided in the update - this should help clear things up. Basically block elements are used for layout, whereas inline elements are used to style bits of text. For example, if you wanted a certain word to be a different style, you'd wrap a span around it. Through CSS you can set the display property of either element to be whatever you want, but this should only be a last resort, as you will most likely end up failing validation and causing more issues.

Comment: Instead of using "block element" and "inline element," use [HTML5 vocabulary](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#kinds-of-content) such as "flow content" and "phrasing content."

Answer (score 1):

*The Spec Ref*: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3

> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other
>   block-level elements. Generally, inline elements may contain only data
>   and other inline elements. Inherent in this structural distinction is
>   the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline
>   elements.

Note the use of words *generally* and *may*. This means ideally inlines should be contained within blocks and not vice-versa.

However, nothing bad happens if you really do. Point here is that it is not recommended.

Also, note that you may change the `display` using css to `block` for `span` which, will *effectively* make it a div!

Coming back to your problem, it is not clear from your question, exactly what problem you are facing . Simply saying "*I am facing many issues with IE7*", will not suffice. You have to let us know *what* issues you are facing. Unless you do that, this question may be a candidate for being put on hold/close.