# div in span, how to make it valid

Tags: css, html

I have this. But the div is in the span. but that is not valid html. So how to make it valid?

```
<span id="breakingnews">
<div id="breakingnewstext">
    <se:embeduri location="http://www.hengelo.nl/intranet-homepage-nieuws.html" />     
</div>
        </span>
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [To Display DIV element inside SPAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432397/to-display-div-element-inside-span)

Answer (score 4):

You can change it to be:

```
<div id="breakingnews">
    <div id="breakingnewstext">
        <se:embeduri location="http://www.hengelo.nl/intranet-homepage-nieuws.html" />     
    </div>
</div>
```

In other words, if a `div` in a `span` is invalid, the best way to make it valid is to just not put a `div` in a `span`

Answer (score 0):

If you need a display:block inside a span why not just replace the span with a div? This way it won't be unpredictable in other browsers as that won't validate.