# Ckeditor swaps span, how to solve?

Tags: html, ckeditor

Sorry for my English

When i put this code into Source:

```
<span><div>TEST</div></span>
```

And then ckick in Source, and then click again, it show this code:

```
<div><span>TEST</span></div>
<span></span>
```

My config:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = 0;
//CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['span'] = 0;
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false; //OR TRUE - the same problem
```

I found [How to display a <div> element inside a <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432397/how-to-display-a-div-element-inside-a-span) that is not correct way: Wrap a div in span

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this for Source:

```
<div><span>Test</span></div>
```

Comment: I know, but i paste much code from other pages into editor and have the same problems.