# Make element not affected by CSS rules

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

My google chrome extension needs to wrap content of certain elements on page user is browsing into custom element, say, `<xelem>original content</xelem>`. This change should not make any visible effect.

Is it possible to make `<xelem>` NOT affected by `*` css rules (or any other rules that might apply to it), but at the same time retain inherited styles?

Comment: Closely related: [Layout-neutral tag for CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751765/layout-neutral-tag-for-css)

Comment: This sentence `Is it possible to make <xelem> NOT affected by any rules that might apply to it, but at the same time retain inherited parent styles` sounds like a contradiction to me. Could you please maybe provide some example?

Comment: @serg: `Inspect element` in Chrome (any element). In Styles tab you'll see `Matched CSS Rules` and a bunch of `Inhereted from ...` underneath. I want the former to never apply whilst preserving the latters.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are working with css3, have a look at the [:not](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) pseudo-class.

Something like

```
:not(xelem) {
    /* ... */
}
```

should work...

Comment: I don't see how it is applicable in this case. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well it's the only way I know excluding tags from defined applicable css rules. Applying `:not()` to existing `*` css which might apply to `<xelem>` should exclude `<xelem>` encapsulated elements from your definitions. I never heard of any global non-css-affected tag... This would contradict known css selector schemes and the principle of cascades. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: The trick is HOW to change `*` to `:not(xelem)` on a page I don't control.